# Determine if valid kernel or not

Tags: linear-algebra

Can you help me to confirm if this is the right approach for determine a valid kernel function?

$ k(x, x') = \tanh(3x^Tx' - 8) $ a valid kernel function?

To determine if this function is a valid kernel, we must show that it corresponds to an inner product in some feature space.

My attempt:

Let's consider the function $ k(x, x') = \tanh(3x^Tx' - 8) $. We can rewrite this function as:

$$ k(x, x') = \tanh(3\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i x'_i - 8) $$

where $ x $ and $ x' $ are vectors in $ \mathbb{R}^n $. We can rewrite the inner product $ x^T x' $ as:

$$ x^T x' = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i x'_i $$

Now, let's define a feature map $ \phi: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m $ where $ m $ is some possibly infinite-dimensional space. We can define the feature map as:

$$ \phi(x) = \tanh(3x_1 - 8), \tanh(3x_2 - 8), \ldots, \tanh(3x_n - 8) $$

Now, let's consider the inner product of the feature vectors $ \phi(x) $ and $ \phi(x') $:

$$ \phi(x)^T \phi(x') = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \tanh(3x_i - 8) \tanh(3x'_i - 8) $$

This inner product is equal to $ k(x, x') $, so we have shown that the function $ k(x, x') = \tanh(3x^Tx' - 8) $ corresponds to an inner product in some feature space, and thus it is a valid kernel function.

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT a valid kernel and it can be seen easily by considering $k(0,0) = \tanh(-8) < 0$. The problem with your proof lies in the claim that $\phi(x)^T \phi(x') = k(x,x')$.